# findViewById() must not be null

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make a navigation drawer. I've made the layout file for the drawer, assigned the views appropriate IDs, and then in the kotlin file I've declared the variables corresponding to the Views using the `lateinit` keyword. Inside the `onCreate()` method I've initialised these variables using `findViewById(R.id...)`

When I run the code, the app crashes and the logcat shows me a **NullPointerException** saying that **findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout) must not be null**. Here is my code for reference:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
lateinit var coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout
lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
lateinit var frameLayout: FrameLayout
lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
    coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout)
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout)
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)
    setUpToolbar()

    val actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this@MainActivity,
        drawerLayout,
        R.string.open_drawer,
        R.string.close_drawer)

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)    
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
}


fun setUpToolbar(){
    supportActionBar?.title = "Toolbar Title"       
    supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) 


 }
}
```

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity = "start"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've tried almost everything under the sun, including

1. declaring the variables in this way: `var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = null`, which helps me avoid the **nullPointerException** in the findViewById line but gives me a whole other level of hell in further part of my code where I have to add click listeners to the toggle using `drawerLayout?.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)`. I asked a [question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794744/smart-cast-to-drawerlayout-is-impossible-because-drawerlayout-is-a-mutable) regarding this error I face with the click listener and the general consensus was to not use this way of declaring `drawerLayout` so as to not make it nullable.
2. I've tried using the non null asserted call this way: `var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout!!` but it still throws me the same error
3. I've checked and rechecked and checked and rechecked the ID of my `DrawerLayout` tag in the layout file since everyone says the exception might be due to the ID and the variable name being different but that's not the case as well. I've even cleared and rebuilt the project, invalidated caches, still no change.

I have no idea how to proceed with this. I've been stuck with this error for the longest time and nothing seems to be working. It'd be great if someone could point out where I'm going wrong

Comment: Can you please add your XML code too?

Comment: @ShobhithYadav sure

Comment: Is `activity_main.xml` the posted xml?

Comment: @Sdghasemi yes it is

Comment: Are you sure the `R` class you're importing belongs to your app package and what happens if you run your code with `drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)`  line commented?

Comment: I tried your code and it is working fine for me...Can you tell me when exactly you got this error while opening your activity? or while opening drawer? or while clicking on some options?

Comment: @Sdghasemi so I definitely do have the` R `class, just checked. When I comment out `drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)` it moves onto the next variable coordinator layout and tells me that `findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout)` must not be null.

Comment: @ShobhithYadav when I run the code on my emulator, the activity crashes. It appears on the screen for like a millisecond and then disappears

Comment: Considering the result, the problem is somehow comes from a problem in inflating the view. The activity somehow fails to bind the view and yields to a null return from `findViewById()`. I suggest you to inflate the view yourself and set it to your activity via `setContentView(View)` to make sure of your view inflation. Also you can use [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) or [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) to automatically find the inflated views.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, it also runs fine on my device, same as Shobhith Yadav pointed out. Maybe you have some corrupted cache, try clearing them: Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... and restart your project.

Answer (score 0):

Using **lazy** instead of **lateinit** will help you avoid your "hell" also

instead of
lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

use

```
val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout by lazy{
  findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
}
```

also you will no longer need

```
drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
```

drawerLayout will get initialized first time it is needed

More [info](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#lazy-properties) here if you are interested.

Comment: I tried it out and it's giving me this error: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: <get-drawerLayout>(...) must not be null` and in the next two lines it's telling me the error is in the line `val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout by lazy {` and `val actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this@MainActivity, drawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer)`

Comment: Oh I didn't notice at first but you are missing AppBarConfiguration, that could be the problem. Here is official docs.
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration