# What happen to the activity when i press back button?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

When I am on activity A(Here LoginActivity) and went to activity B(Here MainActivity) using Intent and also call finish() function
after Intent function
Example:

```
 if (isloggedIn){
        val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
```

And from Activity B(Here MainActivity) when I press back button what will happen will Activity A again will be called by onCreate() or since it is out of the stack it i will be directed to my Homescreen of mobile?
I am currently have the error which make me confused about this:
I have made two Activity (A and B) mentioned above and uses AutoLogin feature for it. It works fine when user login for the first time but when user stops the app and clear the ram and again reopen the app it successfully went to Activity B(MainActivity) without asking Login credential of the user, but when I press back then the app crashes why?
Code:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
lateinit var phone_num:EditText
lateinit var password_num:EditText
lateinit var button_login:Button
lateinit var txtForgotPassword:TextView
lateinit var RegisterYouself:TextView
val ValidMobileNumber="0123"
val ValidPassword= arrayOf("Iron","captain","hulk","avenger")
lateinit var SharedPreferences:SharedPreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    SharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.Prefereces_file_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    val isloggedIn=SharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn",false)

    if (isloggedIn){
        val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }




    title="Log In"

    phone_num=findViewById(R.id.phone_num)
    password_num=findViewById(R.id.password_num)
    button_login=findViewById(R.id.button_login)
    txtForgotPassword=findViewById(R.id.txtForgotPassword)
    RegisterYouself=findViewById(R.id.RegisterYouself)

    button_login.setOnClickListener{
        val mobilenumber=phone_num.text.toString()
        val password=password_num.text.toString()
        var nameOfAvenger="Avenger"
        val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
        if (mobilenumber==ValidMobileNumber){
            if (password==ValidPassword[0]){

                nameOfAvenger="Iron Man"
                savePreferences(nameOfAvenger)

                startActivity(intent)
            }
            else if (password==ValidPassword[1]){

                nameOfAvenger="Captain America"
                savePreferences(nameOfAvenger)

                startActivity(intent)
            }
            else if(password==ValidPassword[2]){

                nameOfAvenger="Hulk"
                savePreferences(nameOfAvenger)

                startActivity(intent)
            }
            else if (password==ValidPassword[3]){

                nameOfAvenger="The Avenger"
                savePreferences(nameOfAvenger)

                startActivity(intent)
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@LoginActivity, "Incorrect creditial", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@LoginActivity, "Incorrect creditial", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }
}
fun savePreferences(title:String){
    SharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn",true).apply()
    SharedPreferences.edit().putString("Title",title).apply()

}
```

}

Error:

```
Process: com.mustafa.activitylifecycle, PID: 26158
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mustafa.activitylifecycle/com.mustafa.activitylifecycle.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.phone_num) must not be null
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.phone_num) must not be null
    at com.mustafa.activitylifecycle.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.kt:43)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
```

Comment: You can simply run this code and see what happens!!! Did you encounter any unexpected behaviour while executing this code?

Comment: yes when i press backbutton my app crashed

Comment: What was the error? Edit your question to include the stacktrace

Comment: Please check I have edit the question

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798556/findviewbyid-must-not-be-null) helps you ?

Comment: What if found till now is that if i remove setContentView from else block then everything works fine but I don't know the actual reason.

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.phone_num)` Where do you have this statement? In LoginActivity? Add some more code from your LoginActivity (after the if-else)

Comment: okay added my whole code

Comment: [Code samples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. Please read the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Problem:**

You have written code that only calls `setContentView` if the user is not logged in. So when the user *is* logged in, there are no views to find.

```
if (isloggedIn){
    val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish() // JUST BECAUSE YOU CALL FINISH DOES NOT MEAN THE METHOD STOPS EXECUTING
}
else {
    // CONTENT ONLY BEING SET IF NOT LOGGED IN
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
}

title="Log In"

// IF NOT LOGGED IN, THERE IS NO "phone_num" TO FIND!!!! CRASH! BOOM!
phone_num=findViewById(R.id.phone_num)
password_num=findViewById(R.id.password_num)
```

**The Solution**

Either always call `setContentView` so the view are available regardless of if you're logged in or not:

```
if (isloggedIn){
    val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}

// REMOVE THE "else" - ALWAYS SET VIEWS SO THEY'RE VALID
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

title="Log In"

phone_num=findViewById(R.id.phone_num)
password_num=findViewById(R.id.password_num)
```

OR ... just do an early return:

```
if (isloggedIn){
    val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
    return // EARLY RETURN TO PREVENT THE REST OF THE IRRELEVANT CODE FROM RUNNING
}
else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
}

title="Log In"

phone_num=findViewById(R.id.phone_num)
password_num=findViewById(R.id.password_num)
```

OR ... extract your view set up logic into a function that is part of the else block:

```
fun onCreate(...) {
    if (isloggedIn) {
        val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
    else {
        initializeActivity()
    }
}

fun initializeActivity() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    title="Log In"

    phone_num=findViewById(R.id.phone_num)
    password_num=findViewById(R.id.password_num)
    // ETC
}
```

Comment: Does code below the finish function also run?

Comment: The code _after_ the `finish` function _call_ will run, yes. Calling `finish` does not just abruptly end execution of the method you're in.

Comment: But it destroys the activity then what is the use of it?

Comment: It _instructs_ the `Activity` to _be_ destroyed. This is different and separate from the computer executing the lines of code that it has been instructed to execute. Calling `finish` tells the Activity to shutdown - it does not tell the JVM to stop executing code, which it will blindly do.

Comment: And once we call finish() and move to another activity then (just like what i did  ) and then press back will it again come back to loginActivity and if yes then why once we call finish() then it should be removed from Activity stack and i should land to my mobile homepage but it is not happening why?

Comment: No, it won't. If you're experiencing this you have a bug and should post a new question.